Derivation of expectation with subscript
I am going through the derivation for Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (DDPMs) based on Calvin Luo's Diffusion tutorial, where he finally develops the reconstruction term, the prior matching term and the denoising matching term.
As for the denoising matching term, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{t}, \mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_0)} \left[ \log  \frac{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t)}{q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)} \right]$$
And somehow, this is turned into the following KL divergence:
$$- \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \mathbf{x}_0)} \left[ \mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}} (q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0) \mid\mid p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t)) \right]$$
I don't understand how the former turns into the latter. I undestand how the sign changes by flipping numerator and denominator in the logarithm, and therefore it looks very similar to the KL divergence.
However: how do the subscripts of the expectation change? I guess it is related to the chain rule of probability but I found very little info online about the properties of expectations with subscripts.

If the subscripts bother you, just change the variable names: this is mere notation, after all.  For instance, you could write "$Y$" for "$x_t,$" $X$ for "$x_{t-1},$" and you can drop all references to "$x_0$" (which can readily be furnished from the context).  After doing that, do you still have a question to ask, or does that resolve the issue for you?

@whuber Thank you, but even this way I still don't know how the $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$ in the Expectation subscript drop. I am unsure on what property/properties are being used here to turn that expectation into another expectation of the KL divergence

It doesn't "drop."  Where do you think that happens?  Have you applied the definition of the KL divergence?  Remember, that, too, is an expectation.

Well: with dropping I meant that it disappears from the subscript. What I cannot understand is how the subscript splits into two: the part that goes to the KL divergence and the part that remains in the expectation

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation.  (I thoroughly agree that the awful notation here is getting in the way of seeing what's going on!)

I indeed thought of the tower rule, but the subscript notation is what is preventing me to believe it can be derived from it into the second expression

Seems someone asked a very similar question here. Does this help clarify?

@cinch indeed, it looks like the same question. Thank you. Unfortunately, the only answer is wrong and there is no mistake in notation

@randomforest42 since you claimed to believe the only answer is wrong but obviously without knowing the truly correct, can you help clarify or improve it using your extra knowledge of the so called wrong answer?

@cinch by the definition of KL divergence the log denominator and the subscript in expectation have to be the same. However, in this case are not. Therefore, the expectation should remain after turning the log to KL divergence. But I am unsure of the exact reason for why the expectaction subscript can be splitted

But if you read on, the authors discussed all three divergence terms and it seems the expectation operators don't have any impact in the said discussion.

Indeed it does not, but I would still want to know what is going on there (as expectations and their properties are kind of a dark art for me)

@randomforest42 after reading more carefully about all the involved conditional random variables q-distributions in diffusion process and p-distributions in reverse diffusion process of the diffusion model, I've updated my answer there.

Changing the notation might help clear things up.  Lacking context, I am guessing about the intended meaning, but let's see where these lead.
Evidently, "$(x_t,x_{t-1})$" is an ordered pair of random variables.  (The bold "$\mathbf x$" suggests they might be vector-valued, so let $d$ be the number of components of the first and $e$ the number of components of the second.)  Because the question is concerned about subscripts, I will drop them and rename these variables $(X,Y).$
Some things are conditioned on "$x_0,$" but because that appears to play no role in the equation, let's just drop the explicit references to it.
The expression "$p_\theta$" looks like a conditional probability density function.  I will drop the superfluous (in this context) "$\theta$" and refer to it as $p_{Y\mid X}$ (to remind us of its role). The conditioning on $x_t$ means that $p_{Y\mid X}$ is being considered as a probability element in $x_{t-1}$ and that it includes $x_t$ as an auxiliary parameter.  Switching to the $(X,Y)$ notation, this merely says the authors are working with the expression
$$p_{Y\mid X}(y, x)\mathrm dy$$
inside the expectation operator and that the expectation itself is multiplying this by the marginal probability element for $x,$
$$p_X(x)\mathrm dx.$$
Similarly, it looks like $q$ is intended to be a joint distribution density, whose probability element we might write as
$$q_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy.$$
Analogous to $p,$ let its associated conditional probability element be
$$q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)\mathrm dy$$
and marginal probability element as
$$q_X(x)\mathrm dx.$$
These three are related by the "tower law of expectation,"
$$q_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy = q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)\mathrm dy \ q_X(x)\mathrm dx.$$
One way to understand the first expression replaces "$\mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{t}, \mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_0)} $" by a double integral $\iint_{\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^e}\ \cdots\ q_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy.$
Turn now to the argument of the expectation operator,
$$\log \frac{p_\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t)}{q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)} = -\log  \frac{q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)}{p_{Y\mid X}(y, x)}.$$
This is a function of the variables $(x,y),$ so it can be applied to the random variables $(X,Y)$ to create a random variable whose expectation is found by integrating this function against the joint probability element:
$$\begin{aligned}
E_{X,Y}\left[-\log  \frac{q_{Y\mid X}(Y, X)}{p_{Y\mid X}(Y, X)}\right] &= -\iint_{\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^e}\log  \frac{q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)}{p_{Y\mid X}(y, x)}\ q_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy\\ &= -\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left( \int_{\mathbb R^e}\log \frac{q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)}{p_{Y\mid X}(y, x)} q_{Y\mid X}(y, x)\mathrm dy\right) q_X(x)\mathrm dx\\
&= -\int_{\mathbb R^d} \mathcal D_{\text{KL}}(p_{Y\mid X}\mid\mid q_{Y\mid X})\,q_X(x)\mathrm dx\\
&= -E_X\left[\mathcal D_{\text{KL}}(p_{Y\mid X}\mid\mid q_{Y\mid X})\right].
\end{aligned}$$
The second line expresses the tower law, the third line replaces the inner ($y$) integral by the definition of the KL divergence, and the last line is the integral representation of the expectation.

Thank you! Everything makes sense except for the actual tower rule… In the equation right below where you write "tower law of expectation", I see basically the chain rule of probability… Could you point to some resource that shows how the tower rule would yield that expression?

With the chain rule of probability I refer to: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability) - first equation in section "Chain rule for events"

Although related, the tower law and the chain rule are different.  The tower law is an immediate consequence of any definition of conditional expectation.

By the looks of it, the tower law implicitly uses the chain rule when the expectation is expressed as integrals. However, I can't find any definition of the tower law matching your answer

That might be because the second line can be analyzed in two steps where the first step invokes the usual formula for a conditional density and the second is Fubini's Theorem.

I don't think that the tower law is of use here… Since it states that E[X] = E[E[X | Y]], but here we have a joint expectation to start with. Furthermore, what you refer to when you say "the usual formula for a conditional density" I guess it is the chain/product rule of probability.

The joint expectation is the left hand side.  The right hand side decomposes it as a sequence of two expectations: first, the expectation of the conditional distribution; then, the expectation of the resulting random variable.  That's exactly what's going on here.

So, what you are implying is the following. For the tower rule: $\mathbb{E}{A, B}[X] = \mathbb{E}{B}[\mathbb{E}{A \mid B}[X \mid B]]$, where (according to the original notation) $A = \mathbf{x}{t-1}$, $B = \mathbf{x}t$ and $X = \log \frac{p\theta(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}t)}{q(\mathbf{x}{t-1}, \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x_0})}$. Therefore, applying the tower law formula we end up with: (continues in next comment)

... $\mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}t \mid \mathbf{x}0)} \left[ \mathbb{E}{q(\mathbf{x}{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}t, \mathbf{x}0)}\left[ \log \frac{p\theta(\mathbf{x}{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}t)}{q(\mathbf{x}{t-1}, \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x_0})} \mid \mathbf{x_t} \right] \right]$ Is this what you mean?

And I guess that given that everything in the log is already conditioned on $\mathbf{x}_t$ that extra-conditioning at the right of the fraction can be dropped...

Those formulas don't make perfect sense.  Check out our explanations of conditional expectations.  If you don't want to work through the sigma-algebra stuff, then what I suggest is to consider the expectation notation as a shorthand for the integrals I present here and take it from there.

Indeed, applying the law of the unconscious statistician to the "original" expectation (therefore turning it into the double integral) everything is obvious and simple.
I was just curious on how the tower rule can be applied here, but I believe I won't be able to understand it without matching the rule with the specific expectation presented in the question. Otherwise I can't see what is wrong with my comment 2 lines above
